# How can I add normal text in front of a hyper link on my ascx page

Tags: html, asp.net, .net, ascx

I am wanting to add normal text in front of a hyper link text.
I am adding my hyper link as shown in the following code

how can i add a "Go To" in front of the Text = "PreRegistration Work Queues"?

```
<td>
            <asp:HyperLink ID="hyperlink2"
            NavigateUrl="../WorkQueues.aspx"
            Text= "Pre-Registration Work Queues"
            Target="_new"
            runat="server" />
</td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either just add the text there, or add an ASP [Label](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.label?view=netframework-4.8).

```
<asp:Label id="GoToLabel" Text="Go To" runat="server"/>
```

Comment: @inderpreetlahil If this answered your question, mark it as an answer to help other StackOverflow users.